# BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE is not expanding

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I am testing BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE as following:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define PORT_HOST A,B
#define PORT_ADDR 1,2,3,4
#define VAR_DATA x, y, z
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(VAR_DATA)
```

This is what I get after expansion:

```
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(x, y, z)
```

But if I do this:

```
#define SEQ (B)(O)(O)(S)(T)
BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(SEQ) // expands to B, O, O, S, T
```

After expansion, I get:

```
B, O, O, S, T
```

I am using pretty much latest clang on Mac OS. g++ also produces the same results.

I am wondering what is going on here. Why variadic boost preprocessor doesn't expand correctly. I am using boost 1.49.0

Comment: +1 for an unusually perfectly-tagged question. :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. In Boost 1.49, in the header file BOOST/Preprorccessor/config.hpp, **clang** is not being defined to support Variadic marcos. The reason is "not tested".... :(

After enable clang, variadic marco expands as expected.

Comment: Ran into this problem with 1.53 while playing with some MSVC code in Clang using https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx. Your question was luckily the first result when entering searching "clang boost preprocessor" via Google :o)